# Convert numbers to letters in French - php

Tags: php

convert alphabet to numbers
I want to convert numbers to letters, but the problem is that decimal numbers are not converted

I think that the problem in this part of the code

```
if (null !== $fraction && is_numeric($fraction)) {
        $string .= $decimal;
        $words = array();
        foreach (str_split((string) $fraction) as $number) {
            $words[] = $dictionary[$number];
        }
        $string .= implode(' ', $words);
    }
return $string;
    }

    $montant_alph = convert_number_to_words($a)." MAD";
```

Comment: Please explain what it does not do, what you expect that it will do and what you tried. This will help the readers to answer your question

Comment: Please provide sample input and output etc.

Comment: pls all look to this is file text : [http://textuploader.com/o5n1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need str_split to transform the fraction part into an array.

```
$dictionary = array(
    1 => 'zero',
    1 => 'un',
    2 => 'deux',
    3 => 'trois',
    4 => 'quatre',
    5 => 'cinq',
    6 => 'six',
    7 => 'sept',
    8 => 'huit',
    9 => 'neuf',
);
// example 422.6543
$fraction = (integer) 6543;
$decimal = 'quatre deux deux / ';

if (null !== $fraction && is_numeric($fraction)) {
    $string .= $decimal;
    $words = array();
    $fraction = (string) $fraction;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($fraction); ++$i) {
        $words[] = $dictionary[$fraction{$i}];
    }
    $string .= implode(' ', $words);
}
```

Comment: already done, but it does not work
look to this is file text : [http://textuploader.com/o5n1]